# Django + PyOrient : db_create socket.timeout exception in EC2

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, orientdb, orientdb2.2, pyorient

I'm using `orientDB` community version `2.2.35` and `pyorient 1.5.5`.

```
client.db_create(db_name, pyorient.DB_TYPE_GRAPH, pyorient.STORAGE_TYPE_PLOCAL)
```

This runs perfectly fine locally after starting the server.

But when I run the same code on an `ec2` machine, it throws `socket.timeout exception`.

I initially thought it could be a `CORS` issue, but it's not. What else could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Running the orientDB server using **sudo command fixed the issue.**

db_create() tries to modify OSystem/dirty.fl file and I got permission denied exception on server logs.

```
FileNotFoundException: /home/ubuntu/orientdb-community-2.2.35/databases/OSystem/dirty.fl (Permission denied)
```